# Docker default CPU architecture doesn't match host's

Tags: macos, docker

When I create a Docker image using the following `Dockerfile`, I get a Docker image that, upon `Docker inspect`, yields `"Architecture": "amd64"`. The host is a macbook pro with an i7 processor running OS X (El Capitan) 10.11.2: `xnu-3248.20.55~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`. My Docker version is `17.03.1-ce-mac5 (16048)`

I don't understand why the Docker image architecture is different than the host. Is there a way for me to specify the architecture in the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: amd64 and x86_64 is the same thing.

Comment: But my macbook has a 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7. How is that possible?

Comment: Because an i7 implements that architecture.  It is just called different things in MacOS and in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

amd64 (or x86_64) refers to the 64-bit edition for Intel and AMD processors.

> After launching the architecture under the "x86-64" name, AMD renamed it AMD64... x86-64 is still used by many in the industry as a vendor-neutral term, while others, notably Sun Microsystems (now Oracle Corporation) and Microsoft, use x64.

Chek this link for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64